# small code redundancy within while-loops (doesn't feel clean)

Tags: python, organization, redundancy, maintainability

So, in Python (though I think it can be applied to many languages), I find myself with something like this quite often:

```
the_input = raw_input("what to print?\n")
while the_input != "quit":
    print the_input
    the_input = raw_input("what to print?\n")
```

Maybe I'm being too picky, but I don't like how the line `the_input = raw_input("what to print?\n")` has to get repeated. It decreases maintainability and organization. But I don't see any workarounds for avoiding the duplicate code without further worsening the problem. In some languages, I could write something like this:

```
while ((the_input=raw_input("what to print?\n")) != "quit") {
    print the_input
}
```

This is definitely *not* Pythonic, and Python doesn't even allow for assignment within loop conditions AFAIK.

This valid code fixes the redundancy,

```
while 1:
    the_input = raw_input("what to print?\n")
    if the_input == "quit":
        break
    print the_input
```

But doesn't feel quite right either. The `while 1` implies that this loop will run forever; I'm using a loop, but giving it a fake condition and putting the real one inside it.

Am I being too picky? Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps there's some language construct designed for this that I don't know of?

Comment: I think the first form is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: This is a common pattern called [loop and a half](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Think **iterators** -- e.g., in this specific case:

```
for the_input in iter(lambda: raw_input('what to print?\n'), 'quit'):
    print the_input
```

Most loops in Python, except at the very lowest levels of abstractions, are best implemented as `for` loops with the help of some underling iterator which captures the "looping logic" -- the `iter` built-in can help (like here), sometimes genexps (generator expressions) can, sometimes the standard library module `itertools` comes to the rescue.

Most often you will choose to code custom *generator functions* (ones using `yield`), or more occasionally (when you need really sophisticated state management) a custom *iterator class* (one defining the `__iter__` special method as `return self`, and `next` [[or `__next__` in the latest versions of Python]] to return "the next value from the iteration).

Capturing the looping logic apart from whatever it is that you *do* on the various items sequentially produced by the loop itself is the key abstraction-helper here!

Comment: +1: Prefer `for`-loops for iteration. In any language that provides them.

Comment: This is an amazing solution. SO won't let me accept an answer for another 4 minutes though ;-)

Comment: @Robert, why "too clever"?  It's **the** best way to do application-level loops in Python -- sequester the looping logic (how do you initiate a loop's next leg and decide when the loop is done) away from the application logic of "what do you **do** with the results of each leg of the loop".  Built-ins like `iter`, standard library modules like `itertools`, entire language constructs like generators and genexps, exist essentially to support this crucial style choice which you deem "too clever"!  Care to expand on your pithy condemnation...?

Comment: @wallacoloo, that's OK, I'll wait patiently for 4 more minutes;-).

Comment: I **do** like the use of iter(callable, sentinel) (didn't know about that before), but I don't really like the use of the lambda (though I don't really expect you to define a function for a small example like this) (I would just like the look of "for line in iter(prompt, 'quit'):")

Comment: (and by *you* I am referring to Alex...)

Comment: @Terence, I'm no lambda-fan either, but two-arg `iter` needs an argument-less callable as its first item and `lambda` is the most concise way to make one, esp. when no logic is needed, just some trivial adaptation, like here (functools.partial is an alternative, but [[beyond the fact it's nowhere as concise, sigh]] I feel hostile to it ever since it cravenly avoided the proper name for that functionality, "currying"!-).